# Compile time check if parameter is annotated using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, lint

I have a requirement in my Android project where I need to validate an argument's annotation.
For eg in below function , I need to ensure if block has the required annotation otherwise throw compilation error or lint error

```
fun doSomething(block : () -> Unit){}
```

1. Is there some annotation processing that could help me here
2. Or can lint check help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code cleaner I would suggest to use lint checks, however there is a way to achieve this programatically.

You can use reflection on parameters.

```
val isAnnotated: Boolean = block::check.hasAnnotation<SomeAnnotation>()

if (!isAnnotated) throw Exception()
```

Comment: This check would happen at runtime, right? I want something like this to be checked during compilation.
Also, can you provide any pointers on how to achieve this via lint checks?

Comment: @prateek I think you can use this doc https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/api-guide.html#annotations/basics
You can also write unit tests that will perform the check from the answer